# pop up the excel file instead of saving internally in apache poi

Tags: java, spring, apache-poi, file-handling

i need to generate a file in a popup after converting to the excel file. i'm using apache poi for this.

Here is my code:

```
try {
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\update.xls"));

   **excel coding here..**

    file.close();

    FileOutputStream outFile =new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\update.xls"));
    workbook.write(outFile);
    outFile.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

what can i do in the FileOutputStream or something else and let user save it wherever they want?

Comment: How is the user interacting with your code? Swing? AWT? Web?

Comment: its a webapplication built in spring.

Answer (score 2):

you are hard-coding the url **C:\update.xls** to file. Depending on your project, u can make a UI, add there ( a text field, where user can type desired file-name\path, or file-choose dialog). Or you can read file path from console. After retrieving the path, you create file with

> FileOutputStream outFile =new FileOutputStream(new File(NewFilePath))

Comment: not a probable solution. I wanna throw a popup to the user so that they can store it wherever they want. Its bad to ask them to enter the path.